# Check if variable is a child type of type union

Tags: typescript, types, enums, union-types

Say I had 2 enums: Mammals and Fish

```js
enum Mammal {
    bear = 'bear', 
    human = 'human'
}
enum Fish { 
    salmon = 'salmon', 

}
```

I then merged those enums:

```js
const Animal = { Mammals, Fish };
type Animal = Mammals | Fish;
```

When typecasting a variable into that parent how would I find what child enum it is part of?

`let animal = <Animal>'salmon'`

Essentially what I want is something like this:

```js
if (typeof <Animal> 'salmon' == typeof Mammal) {
//do stuff...
}
```

Comment: There is nothing preventing the same value appearing in multiple 'child' enums, so there is no logical way of inferring this. Also, `typeof` when used as a statement like this will always give you `'string'`.

Comment: That's a shame. Is there some other way to implement this sort of feature? The method of implementation doesn't matter to me as long as I can derive a child type from a parent type.

Comment: Well, if you use classes with inheritance you can use `instanceof` to do the comparison. But for construction you would need to e.g. create a factory function that maps a string to the correct sub-class.

Comment: If you create this as an answer I'll mark it correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing preventing the same value appearing in multiple 'child' enums, so there is no logical way of inferring this. Also, `typeof` when used as a statement like this will always give you `'string'`.

A different approach would be using classes with inheritance, that way [`intanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) can be used in the comparison. You could use a factory function that maps a string to the correct sub-class to create the instances.